# How to use alias names for variables?

Tags: c++

I want to improve my code, is there an other way to **assingn an alias name** for 
*parent->values[i-1]*? 
 The isssue is that values [i - 1] isn't really intention revealing, however the reference costs some runtime.

```
if (belegt < k) {
     if (prev && prev->belegt > k && prev->parent == parent) {
          for (size_t i = 0; i <= parent->belegt; i++) {
               if (parent->leafptr[i] == this) {
                    Key &above = parent->values[i - 1];
                    Key &previous = prev->values[prev->belegt - 1];

                    add(above, leafptr[0]);

                    leafptr[0] = prev->leafptr[prev->belegt];
                    leafptr[0]->setParent(this);

                    parent->replace_rekursiv(above, previous);

                    prev->belegt--;
                    break;
                }
           }
```

I thought of something like

```
using above = previous = prev->values[prev->belegt - 1];
```

but that won´t do the trick?

Comment: Are you sure the reference is costing you anything?  Per the standard a reference doesn't have to occupy any space.

Comment: It is most likely that dummy references will be optimized anyway. So don't bother.

Comment: Unless you need efficiency, and you've benchmarked and verified that it has a cost, just use a reference - premature optimisation is the root of all evil.

Comment: Using references in this manner does not cost you anything. The compiler knows the address of the referred to memory, and that you are referring to it using another name. This abstraction won't end up in the produced machine code. You can test this yourself on https://godbolt.org.

Answer (score 2):

> is there any other way to assign an alias name for parent->values[i-1]?

As far as I know, the only one good way is to create a reference and work with this reference as you already did:

```
Key &above = parent->values[i - 1];
```

Your assumption about run time cost seems to be incorrect - any sane compiler will optimize this code away, so you might not bother.

Comment: okay then i trust the compiler. I also should avoid premature optimization. Thank you

Comment: @dreiti yes, that's what I mean :)

Comment: Assuming OP is compiling *with* optimizations enabled ;-)

Comment: @JesperJuhl I hope so!

Comment: IMHO, you should use the reference to make the code easier to read.